# CFBundleDevelopmentRegion doesn't work while setting not supportive language

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, bundle

I'm designing an app which supports English, German and Simple Chinese(The app default is English).

However, while I set a language (like German, supportive language) to launch my app, it's normal. Then I set another language (like Korean, not supportive) and launch the app. The app still shows German version but English.

I'm pretty sure my CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is set en.

What to do to make the app show English version in other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
First, go to info.plist to see CFBundleDevelopmentRegion
Before Xcode 7, we only need to choose the language as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM7Bl.png)

We want English to be default language. Then we set "en".
However, Xcode 7 update Localization choices for same language.
Like en-UK and en-US are actually English.

So just choose the Localization wiz country

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwebL.png)

I choose United State then the bug is solved.